# How to get solana token address from mint address?

Tags: web3.js

How to get solana token address from mint address using solana/web3.js?

for examples, in the case of https://solscan.io/address/AtRGBFrgzy3iYcRjyRLkQCjQrBpXEnP5PH2xgpxPt6EN?cluster=devnet

How to get 'AtRGBFrgzy3iYcRjyRLkQCjQrBpXEnP5PH2xgpxPt6EN' from '89dre8rZjLNft7HoupGiyxu3MNftR577ZYu8bHe2kK7g'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the associated token address for the mint `89dre8rZjLNft7HoupGiyxu3MNftR577ZYu8bHe2kK7g` and the owner `72QTssce1DbnmkbytEewssHMd4xGxUY3faEF8RGoBZde`. You need to know both pieces of information to derive the associated token address.

Once you know those, you can get it like this:

```
const { getAssociatedTokenAddress } = require('@solana/spl-token')
const { PublicKey } = require('@solana/web3.js')

async function main() {
  const mint = new PublicKey('89dre8rZjLNft7HoupGiyxu3MNftR577ZYu8bHe2kK7g')
  const owner = new PublicKey('72QTssce1DbnmkbytEewssHMd4xGxUY3faEF8RGoBZde')

  const tokenAddress = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(mint, owner)
  return tokenAddress.toBase58()
}
```

Replit example: https://replit.com/@mcintyre94/solana-token-mint#index.js